# Big sur 11.2.2 very lagging on 2019 Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, catalina, big-sur

I have a late 2019 macbook pro (the base model). I've been running Catalina until yesterday when I upgraded to Big Sur 11.2.2. It's noticeably laggy. Has anyone experienced this? I'm not sure if 11.2.1 was laggy, so I was considering downgrading. Does anyone know how I can downgrade to 11.2.1, and possibly back to Catalina?

Comment: Why not focus on one question per question? If you have lag - define precisely what you are measuring and if it’s CPU - maybe seeing what the CPU is doing in activity monitor might help us help you.

Comment: @bmike There aren't any quantitative measurements. I just notice the lag especially when I'm typing (characters that I'm typing don't appear immediately).

Comment: OK - I may try to answer the "how to install" question since that may be easily answerable and then you could ask a follow on question on how to diagnose keyboard lag on macOS Big Sur... As you see - just rolling back an OS is a long process if you need to cover all the bases and even longer if you don't use several KB that each are pretty detailed and have multiple steps.

Comment: Can you check what the top CPU consumers are in `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor`? (Make sure to switch to `View -> All Processes` and do a descending sort by CPU usage.)

Comment: @pion Yes, here it is https://imgur.com/a/HuRvtU1. I was exaggerating when I saw "it's VERY laggy." It is laggy. When I'm typing fast, the characters are noticeably lagging behind when I press the key. It was not doing this prior to the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would back date a newer Big Sur system to 11.2.1

If you have a Time Machine Backup from before you ran the upgrade. That means you can erase the Mac - get the installer for 11.2.1 and then erase / install in a fairly straight-forward manner.

Once 11.2.1 is running, migrate data from the Time Machine snapshot or backup interval before the upgrade (or whatever your custom backup procedure entails). If you don't have a backup - make one now so you can hand migrate some of the easy apps and files that are compatible with a downgrade - some apps like Photos databases don't necessarily work backwards so you'd need to handle those errors and issues one by one.

Also - Catalina may have made a snapshot of your system that’s usable as a backup, so you would just boot to recovery and restore the system to that shapshot and not even need to worry about an installer.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015

> And in [macOS High Sierra or later](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201260), another snapshot is saved before installing any [macOS update](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201541).

If you need to make a bootable 11.2.1 installer, here's how:

1. Delete any Install macOS Big Sur apps you have in /Applications (or copy them to an external drive)
2. Open terminal.app or another tool to get to the command line and issue this command

> softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 11.2.1

Once the installer is there, follow this guide to make an installable USB for 11.2.1

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Then follow this guide to erase install.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a time machine backup. I actually just switched over to the 2019 macbook pro last week from my 2015 macbook pro, which was time machine backed up to my external HDD, but I don't have a USB-C cable for the HDD yet, so I haven't done any backups on the 2019 macbook.

Comment: Not the end of the world @user5965026 - get one now while you sort out options. There’s no  harm in getting a backup and then seeing if you can sort the slow and not have to roll back.

Comment: Oh wait, I misread your post yesterday. The MacBook itself may also have a time machine backup (i.e., stored on the actual MacBook)? I wasn't aware that it could do that. That seems to be what the local snapshots link you linked me indicates.

Answer (score 1):

From your *Activity Monitor* screenshots, it looks like you're using Chrome. Chrome is notorious for excessive resource consumption on macOS. I would suggest switching to Safari and using it for a few days to see if your lag disappears.